# What happens in a scattering between a infrared radiation photon and a microwave photon?

Tags: scattering

Complete question: A scattering between a infrared radiation photon and a microwave photon can be made into a symmetric scattering problem by switching into the center of mass frame?

Quantum-mechanically, there is photon-photon scattering (two-photon physics)

For example a scattering between a microwave photon and an x-ray photon can be made into a symmetric scattering problem by switching into the center of mass frame.

But for other types of radiation, for example between a infrared photon and a microwave photon?

Comment: What is the center of mass of a system with no massive objects?

Comment: @ThePhoton I guess you know the answer to that.

Comment: @my2cts, I think I know which frame OP wants, but I don't see why it's called the "center of mass" frame. (given we're not supposed to talk about "relativistic mass" any more)

Comment: The center of mass frame is a nonrelativistic approximation to the frame with vanishing momentum.